# Stop jquery library after route change in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I use the following jquery library to convert vertical scroll to horizontal scroll.

```
ngOnInit() {
  $(function() {
    $('html, body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        document.querySelector('.coverflow').scrollLeft -= (delta / 4);
    });
  });
}
```

It works fine, but changing the route will return errors.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollLeft' of null

Obviously that's because after changing the route, `.coverflow` won't exist anymore - **but how do I stop Angular from executing the code** f.e. inside of `ngOnDestroy`?

Comment: You need to check if '.coverflow' exists than only set scrollLeft. you can check like document.documentElement.contains('.coverflow');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Removing Event Handlers

If you wanted to remove the mousewheel binding, you could use the [`off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) function to stop listening for that event in the appropriate selector:

```
// This will stop any mousewheel event listeners
$('html, body').off('mousewheel');
```

If you are explicitly using a plugin to handle this in jQuery such as [jquery-mousewheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel), then you could use the aptly named `unmousewheel` function as well:

```
$('html, body').unmousewheel();
```

### Conditionally Scrolling

An alternative to removing the handlers entirely would be to simply update the body of your event handler and only perform a scroll *if* the appropriate element exists:

```
$('html, body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    // Find the element to scroll
    let scrollElement = document.querySelector('.coverflow');
    if(scrollElement){
        // Scroll it if it exists
        scrollElement.scrollLeft -= (delta / 4);
    }
});
```